# Kibana 3.1.2 freeze my browser

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I'm using kibana 3.1.2 with ES cluster ( 2 servers ) everything works fine with the kibana UI until we add the second ES server to the cluster .

After i added the seconds ES server to the cluster i have a lot of pending requests from the kibana and my browser hangs a lot !

I can see this request :

```
Remote Address:***.***.***.***:9200
Request URL:http://***.***.***.***:9200/logstash-******/_search
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
```

This took 36 seconds !

EDIT NUMBER 1 :

Using marvel query i got very fast response :

```
{
   "took": 1219,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 14,
      "successful": 14,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 23115,
      "max_score": 0,
      "hits": []
   },
   "aggregations": {
      "seaerchUnique": {
         "value": 7773
      }
   }
}
```

Please advice .

Thanks ,
Amit

Comment: Do you experience any delays in query results after connecting the second node if you run queries against ES _search API?

Comment: @OrWeinberger I'm tried with Marvel to run query and i got very fast response i will edit my post and put there the response